# VB.NET что такое Extension

Tags: .net, vb.net

Перенял чужой проект и наткнулся на следующие <Extension()> что это значит? С чем его едят и как его используют? Прочитал на сайте Microsoft, но грубо говоря не понял.

Comment: в таком виде это что угодно может значить. Добавь больше контекста в вопрос

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods